# How to extract the row with min or max values?

Tags: r, max, min

With a dataframe like this one:

```
        ID  Year    Temp    ph
1       P1  1996    11.3    6.80
2       P1  1996    9.7     6.90
3       P1  1997    9.8     7.10
...
2000    P2  1997    10.5    6.90
2001    P2  1997    9.9     7.00
2002    P2  1997    10.0    6.93
```

if I want to know where the max value is I type:

```
which.max(df$Temp)
```

and R print the index of the row, for example 665.

So, if I want to read and extract the column with all the related values, I have to type:

```
df[665, ]
```

Isn't there a simpler way to know which ID is related to the max value of a specific column of the df?

Comment: `df[which.max(df$Temp),]`? Or are you asking something more complicated?

Comment: Ahrrhrh.. I've tried with a lots of methods, but I didn't thought that it could be so simple. Thanks!!

Comment: Also consider `subset(df, Temp == max(Temp))` which gives all the rows whose `Temp` is the maximum (whereas `which.max` solutions give one such row).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can include your `which.max` call as the first argument to your subsetting call:

```
df[which.max(df$Temp),]
```

Comment: what if the vector is bimodal?

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt: see [Gabor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449615/how-to-extract-the-row-with-min-or-max-values/19449769?noredirect=1#comment28839525_19449615). Though you might need to be [careful if `Temp` is a double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/271616).

Answer (score 15):

A (relatively new) alternative is to use `slice_max` (or `slice_min`) from the `tidyverse`. Using `mtcars` as example:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% slice_max(mpg)
#                 mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1 65 4.22 1.835 19.9  1  1    4    1

mtcars %>% slice_min(mpg)
#                      mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
# Lincoln Continental 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
```

---

Note that `slice_max` and `slice_min` give you *all* the rows, which have a max or min value in the specified column (like the call `mtcars[mtcars$mpg == min(mtcars$mpg), ]`. So if you only want the first row (like in the call `mtcars[which.min(mtcars$mpg), ]`), you need to slice once again like:

```
mtcars %>% slice_min(mpg) %>% slice(1)
#                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.25 17.98  0  0    3    4
```

---

Moreover, [`slice`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html) also offers a few more helper functions for common use cases like `slice_head`, `slice_tail` and `slice_sample`.

Comment: Using the `n =` argument, `slice_max` can also show you rows corresponding to the top n values in the specified column.

Answer (score 12):

You could also use a subset and max function to call the row:

```
df[df$Temp == max(df$Temp),]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding the min/max for certain groups, then you can combine group_by and slice_max in tidyverse. In this example, say you wanted to know the max Temp within each year, then you would do the following:

```
df %>% group_by(Temp) %>% slice_max(Temp)
```

Just another way to maximize the tidyverse packages.